# Windows 2012 native VPN: Persistent server-server VPN possible?

Tags: windows

We are working to set up a server to server vpn on two win2012-R2 systems. These systems are in different data centers, and we do not have access to/manage the firewalls/networking gear (aside from opening ports).

The normal way to solve this is to set up an ipsec vpn from firewall to firewall, but as described above, this is not possible for this project.

Since Win2012 has loads of VPN server and client functionality built in, we figure we should be able to use OS tools to do this (like how we use ssh server/client on linux).

(This connection is not for users to use. It is for SQL log shipping, so it is for "server to server" communication.)

The tech I am working with says the vpn will be at the user level, and will close when the user logs out.

I thought we could do it at a "system to system" level, but cannot find docs that are clear one way or the other.

We have a strong preference to use native Win2012-r2 functionality, but will consider commercial and free software based tools if that is the only/much better option.

What is the story?

Comment: What VPN technology will you be using?

Comment: Forgive my ignorance, but what in the world is "OP Enhanced". That is not a VPN technology I've never heard of.

Comment: @EEAA Apologies. Means "original post enhanced" -- that your comment lead me to add needed detail to the original post. Thank you!

Comment: I think a persistent demand-dial connection via RRAS running on both servers should probably do the trick for you.

Comment: Use IPSec in transport mode. It's simple to set up and can be done using native tools.

Comment: @joeqwerty is there a howto or appro doc ? My google-fu hasn't given me much yet.

Comment: TechNet has a boat load of information. - https://www.google.com/?gws_rd=ssl#q=demand-dial+routing

Comment: @EEAA - just post that as the answer; it's definitely correct.

Comment: @EEAA is there a howto or appro doc ? My google-fu hasn't given me much yet.

Comment: @samsmith I'm sure there is. You'll just need to do some research.

Comment: @eeaa I have done considerable research on this, and have not seen anything that addresses the server to server angle. Ergo the question here.

Comment: Forget the fact that it's server to server. Learn about IPSec in general and you'll have all of the concepts you need to get it sorted out. Fire up a few VMs and play with it.

Answer (score 1):

Use IPSec in transport mode. It's simple to set up and can be done using native tools.

I've done this dozens of times on BSD/Linux, but unfortunately never on Windows (though I know it's possible), so I'm not able to provide more details or a pointer to a tutorial. In general, though IPSec is not all that complex to set up. A few IPsec gotchas to consider:

1. All of the settings are identical on both ends of the connection
2. Your Phase 2 configurations are in place to inform the kernel which packets need to be encrypted (matching on destination address)